# The purpose of dot-extension files with json-data

Tags: angularjs, json

In process of my self-study AngularJS and UI Grid, a few times I have seen dot-extension files (i.e. **foobar.dot**) with json data. What is the purpose of it?

```
{
    "Foo":"Abc",
    "Bar":"Xyz"
}
```

For exmaple, the data from [this page](http://www.uakron.edu/academics_majors/class-search/#/course-detail/3000:501:001:4161) is rendered [using the following dot-file](http://www.uakron.edu/academics_majors/class-search/data/course.dot?id=3000:501:001:4161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the dot rule is to make sure the inheritance is in use. With out it scope models might not work as they should in your controller.

For more detailed explanation: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes